# How to check if pairs remain the same between years?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with pairs of individual birds (male and female) that were observed in several years. I am trying to figure out whether these pairs have changed from one year to the next so that I can do some further analyses.

My data is structured like this:

```
dat <- tibble(year = rep(1:3, each = 3),
              Male = c("A1", "B1", "C1",
                       "A1", "B1", "C1",
                       "A1", "B1", "C2"),
              Female = c("X1", "Y1", "Z1",
                         "X1", "Y2", "Z2",
                         "X1", "Y2", "Z2"))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
   year Male  Female
  <int> <chr> <chr> 
1     1 A1    X1    
2     1 B1    Y1    
3     1 C1    Z1    
4     2 A1    X1    
5     2 B1    Y2    
6     2 C1    Z2    
7     3 A1    X1    
8     3 B1    Y2    
9     3 C2    Z2
```

And my expected output is something like:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 5
   year Male  Female male_state female_state
  <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>       
1     1 A1    X1     new        new         
2     1 B1    Y1     new        new         
3     1 C1    Z1     new        new         
4     2 A1    X1     reunited   reunited    
5     2 B1    Y2     divorced   new         
6     2 C1    Z2     divorced   new         
7     3 A1    X1     reunited   reunited    
8     3 B1    Y2     reunited   reunited    
9     3 C2    Z2     new        divorced
```

I cannot figure out how to check whether a value from a different column is the same in the year before (e.g. if the male ID is the same for a certain female in year 2 or 3 as in the year prior). Any ideas?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could spell out what each of your states mean. It seems like the first year an ID appears, it should be "new". In subsequent years, if the mate on the same row is the same as the previous year, then it should be "reunited". If the mate on the same row is different from the previous year, it should be "divorced". Is that correct?

Comment: And that we can assume that each ID shows up at most one per year. Could there be gaps? Like, what if `D1` is present with `W1` in year 1, but in year 2 `D1` is missing and `W1` is with a different mate, and in year 3 `D1` is back with `W1`. Is that possible? If so, what states should  they have?

Comment: Each ID can only show up once a year, yes! I guess it's theoretically possible that a pair reunites after initially divorcing, but I don't expect it to happen in my data set. I suppose I'd still say they are new then. However, there are also missing values in the data (e.g., I might have the ID for only one partner) so a pair that is together in year one, only one partner seen in year two, and together again in year three should probably be reunited in all three years (but there are no such cases in my data at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

This (probably overcomplicated) pipe produces the following output.

```
dat <- tibble(year = rep(1:3, each = 3),
              Male = c("A1", "B1", "C1",
                       "A1", "B1", "C1",
                       "A1", "B1", "C2"),
              Female = c("X1", "Y1", "Z1",
                         "X1", "Y2", "Z2",
                         "X1", "Y2", "Z2"))

dat %>% 
  mutate(pair=paste0(Male,Female)) %>% 
  arrange(pair,year) %>% 
  mutate(check = if_else((pair==lag(pair)) & (year>lag(year)), 'old couple', 'new couple')) %>%
  mutate(check = if_else(is.na(check), 'new couple', check)) %>% 
  mutate(divorced = if_else((Male == lag(Male)) & (Female != lag(Female)), 'divorce', '')) %>%
  mutate(divorced = if_else(is.na(divorced), '', divorced))
```

OUTPUT:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 6
   year Male  Female pair  check      divorced 
  <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>      <chr>    
1     1 A1    X1     A1X1  new couple ""       
2     2 A1    X1     A1X1  old couple ""       
3     3 A1    X1     A1X1  old couple ""       
4     1 B1    Y1     B1Y1  new couple ""       
5     2 B1    Y2     B1Y2  new couple "divorce"
6     3 B1    Y2     B1Y2  old couple ""       
7     1 C1    Z1     C1Z1  new couple ""       
8     2 C1    Z2     C1Z2  new couple "divorce"
9     3 C2    Z2     C2Z2  new couple ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
  year = rep(1:3, each = 3),
  Male = c(
    "A1", "B1", "C1",
    "A1", "B1", "C1",
    "A1", "B1", "C2"
  ),
  Female = c(
    "X1", "Y1", "Z1",
    "X1", "Y2", "Z2",
    "X1", "Y2", "Z2"
  )
)

dat |> 
  mutate(pairing = str_c(Male, "|", Female)) |> 
  add_count(pairing) |> 
  group_by(pairing) |> 
  mutate(male_state = if_else(pairing == lag(pairing), "reunited", NA_character_),
         female_state = if_else(pairing == lag(pairing), "reunited", NA_character_)) |> 
  group_by(Male) |> 
  mutate(
    male_state = if_else(row_number() == 1, "new", male_state),
    male_state = if_else(is.na(male_state), "divorced", male_state)
    ) |> 
  group_by(Female) |> 
  mutate(
    female_state = if_else(row_number() == 1, "new", female_state),
    female_state = if_else(is.na(female_state), "divorced", female_state)
  ) |> 
  arrange(year, Male) 
#> # A tibble: 9 × 7
#> # Groups:   Female [5]
#>    year Male  Female pairing     n male_state female_state
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <int> <chr>      <chr>       
#> 1     1 A1    X1     A1|X1       3 new        new         
#> 2     1 B1    Y1     B1|Y1       1 new        new         
#> 3     1 C1    Z1     C1|Z1       1 new        new         
#> 4     2 A1    X1     A1|X1       3 reunited   reunited    
#> 5     2 B1    Y2     B1|Y2       2 divorced   new         
#> 6     2 C1    Z2     C1|Z2       1 divorced   new         
#> 7     3 A1    X1     A1|X1       3 reunited   reunited    
#> 8     3 B1    Y2     B1|Y2       2 reunited   reunited    
#> 9     3 C2    Z2     C2|Z2       1 new        divorced
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>